# No comment syntax defined when tangling lua or vimrc code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, comment, tangle

### Resolution

With help from commenters, I have things kind of working.

- I removed `:comments link` from Properties.
- I manually added comments to the top of every code block to replicate what `:comments link` would do.
- I had to install modes for each language I was missing (lua, vimrc, maybe others?).

Now I can tangle in Doom Emacs or in default Emacs. I wish I could solve this without manually adding comments, but this is Good Enough®

### Ask

In an org file, how do I define a comment syntax for lua and vimrc?

### Explanation

I am moving all my various config files into 1 org file. When trying to tangle it, I get a prompt "No comment syntax is defined. Use:  " for each lua and vimrc code block. I don't want to have to specify this for every lua and vimrc code block I have, every time I tangle the file, for each block. I don't see a way to specify the comment syntax in the header, but that's the kind of solution I'm looking for.

### Environment

I use [Doom Emacs](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/) in case that's relevant. I'm experiencing this issue on two different machines.

#### Machine 1

- OS: macOS 12.1
- Emacs: GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, Carbon Version 158 AppKit 1671.6) of 2021-03-27
- Org Mode: Org mode version 9.6 (9.6-??-e7ea951ac)

#### Machine 2

I'm not on this machine at the moment so I'm only going by memory here, but I update my software about weekly.

- OS: macOS 12.1
- Emacs: 28.0.92
- Org Mode: 9.6

### Example org file

```
#+TITLE: Configs
#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle yes :mkdirp yes :comments link :tangle-mode (identity #o444)

** Nvim
#+NAME: nvim_init
#+begin_src lua :tangle ~/.config/nvim/init.lua
vim.cmd('set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after')
-- etc
#+end_src

#+NAME: vimrc
#+begin_src vimrc :tangle ~/.vim/vimrc
set nocompatible
" etc
#+end_src
```

- EDIT: Mar 25 Add Environment section
- EDIT: Mar 26 Add Resolution section

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my side. What's your Emacs and Org version.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it either.

Comment: That message is used in function `comment-normalize-vars`. It would be interesting to find out how that gets called. You could instrument the function with e.,g. [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html) and when execution stops in the function, you could get a backrace with `d`. That *might* (or might not) help with debugging the problem.

Comment: @TianshuWang I updated my question with environment details. In short, Emacs 27.2 and 28.0.92, Org Mode 9.6, and macOS 12.1.

Comment: @NickD I updated my question with environment details. In short, Emacs 27.2 and 28.0.92, Org Mode 9.6, and macOS 12.1.

Comment: Emacs 28.0.92 Org 9.5.2. Can you reproduce with `emacs -Q`? If not, I thought you can raise an issue if you can reproduce this with empty doom config.

Comment: @TianshuWang I just tried `emacs -Q <filename>`, did `C-c C-v t` to tangle, and got the same prompt :( Where should I raise the issue? I have no clue where the original emacs source code is.

Comment: @Jason Sorry, I can reproduce now with the full example file. I didn't copy `PROPERTY` before, and I find out it is because you set `:comment link` and Emacs doesn't know the comment syntax for both modes.

Comment: @TianshuWang ok, that makes sense, thanks! But I'm back to my question of, can I define the comment syntax for each code block? If not I'll have to remove `:comment link` but I really like having that info in the tangled files.

Comment: I have things kind of working. I removed `:comments link` from Properties. I manually added comments to the top of every code block. I had to install modes for each language I was missing (lua, vimrc, maybe others?). But now I can tangle in Doom Emacs or in default Emacs. Thanks for all the help! I wish I could solve this less manually but this is Good Enough(r)

Comment: @Jason I think the most convenient way is to install corresponding packages to these modes https://github.com/mcandre/vimrc-mode and https://immerrr.github.io/lua-mode/

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this when writing a config file for which there is no existing major mode.

It looks like Doom Emacs uses the same code that's used by `(comment-dmim)` for `org-babel-tangle`.  So to debug this, you could run with `:comments none` first, then open the generated file, verify that it has the correct major mode, then do `M-x comment-dmim`.

### Installing LUA Mode in Doom Emacs

As it turns out, `lua-mode` is not installed by default in Doom Emacs and it's also not part of that template module list that's provided in the documentation.

However, installing it is quite easy by putting `(package! lua-mode)` into your `packages.el` and `(use-package! lua-mode :defer t)` into your `config.el`.  I am using a literate `config.org` file, so here's how that looks like:

```
Install LUA mode.

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle packages.el
(package! lua-mode)
#+end_src

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(use-package! lua-mode
  :defer t)
#+end_src
```

I have the following at the top of my `config.org`, that's why the second code block doesn't need an explicit file name:

```
#+property: header-args:emacs-lisp :tangle config.el
```

Setting up `vimrc` should work the same way.

### Manual setup for generic files

In case there isn't any existing major mode availabe, one thing you could do is to use `text-mode` and then explicitly configure the comment style for it.

It looks like all that's needed is to `(setq-local comment-use-syntax nil)` and `(setq-local comment-start "// ").

For instance, if you put this into `foo.txt`, load it with the local variables and then do `M-x comment-dmim`, it should work:

```
-*- mode: text; comment-use-syntax: nil; comment-start: "// " -*-

Hello.
```

### Custom Minor Mode

To make this work nicely in Org Mode, I simply defined a custom minor mode:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(define-minor-mode xkb-mode
  "Minor mode for editing XKB config files."
  :lighter nil
  (if xkb-mode
      (progn
        (setq-local comment-use-syntax nil)
        (setq-local comment-start "// ")))
  )
#+end_src
```

And then I can just do

```
#+begin_src xkb :tangle xkd-test
xkb_keycodes "moonlander" {
// Test comment.
};
```

As an added benefit of using the custom minor mode, you can then edit the code block via `org-edit-special` and use `comment-dwim` inside that buffer.